# Can't debug C++ with Qt projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, qt, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a C++ project using Qt libraries, and I'm working with Eclipse onto an Ubuntu virtual machine.

I have three problems right now I would need to solve:

1. Every line of code involving Qt libraries is marked in red as an error. It compiles anyway and the application works, but it is annoying having like 2000 errors which are not.
2. Can't debug. When executing the debugger, it takes very long to load, and after that the debugger never stops at the breakpoints I had set.
3. No references into the code: When I worked with Java, I used to press Control key and then onto a variable or function name, and then automatically went to it's declaration. Since I got this new job, this feature doesn't seem to work with Eclipse CDT.

I need to solve this problems (especially the debugger one). Any help?

Comment: When I started out on Qt I tried Eclipse until I realised Qt Creator was so much better, I would suggest trying it if you can.

Comment: It's not a possibility for me, I just have Eclipse at work :(

Comment: Shame. Anyway, it sounds like Eclipse doesn't know where your Qt headers are. There will be a project (and global) setting somewhere that you can give Eclipse paths to your headers. As for the break points: no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include Qt headers in eclipse please try out the following steps:

right click on project -> select properties -> in properties window select C++ project settings , there you must add the include path which will give the path of qt headers.